# How can I find out the length of a column in a JPA @Entity?

Tags: java, jpa

I've got a String column defined with

```
@Column(length = 4000)
```

The attribute contains log information and can be longer than the defined length. In this case, the field can be safely truncated without throwing an error message.

I'd like to find out the determined length of the column in the DAO class for the pojo so that I can truncate the string if necessary. How can I do that?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: A cheap and easy way to achieve this is using length constants inside your entity class. 

<br><code>
 public static final short FIELD_LENGTH = 255;
</br><br>
 @Column(name="FIELD", length = FIELD_LENGTH)
</br>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out EJB's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816780/how-to-reuse-fieldlength-in-form-validation-and-ddl/1946901#1946901) to this question;

> [How to reuse fieldlength in form, validation and ddl ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816780/)

To paraphrase, if you wanted the length from the firstName column in the person table, you use this code.

```
person.getClass().getDeclaredField("firstName").getAnnotation(Column.class).length()
```

Comment: This will work when the field size is given in the annotation. However, is there a way without the annotation, to learn the real size of the underlying database field?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way to do it would be using [reflection](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/JavaAnnotationAnnotationandReflection.htm) with your annotations. I won't be cheap though, in terms of performance.

Comment: That's what's in place now. I just thought that as a proper OR-Mapper, you could easily access field metadata.

Answer (score 1):

A cheap and easy way to achieve this is using length constants inside your entity class. I think it should be the right way to do it, if you consider columns size is precisely a constant in your entity

Example

```
public static final short FIELD_LENGTH = 255;
@Column(name="FIELD", length = FIELD_LENGTH)
private String field;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection would be an obvious answer.

Are you using Hibernate? If so then the Hibernate Validator should validate the length for you and provide a suitable error message.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate and have considered using Validator but I don't think it would be appropriate. 

The column contains log data which can safely be truncated without throwing an error.

Comment: Then Reflection would be the best way. There's no easy Column.getLength() method unfortunately.

Comment: How would you go about reflecting this?